# Saving ggplot objects for use on different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

We all know we can do

```
p <- ggplot(data)
p + aes(x = funny_hat) + geom_histogram()
```

But I've never seen documentation of the opposite case. Say I want to store a bunch of ggplot objects, e.g.:

```
geom_boxplot() + stat_compare_means(method = "anova", size = 14, vjust = 1) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-2,2.5, 0.5)) + theme(text = element_text(size = 48))
```

... so that I can plug all of that in for different datasets e.g.

```
ggplot(data1) + [all my arguments]
ggplot(data2) + [all my arguments]
```

This doesn't work if I try to use the same method as I would in the first example, but is there a way to do it? I grow tired of copy-pasting...

Comment: Couldnt you just wrap your ggplot arguments in a function? `myFun <- function(ggobject){ ggobject + aes(x = cyl, y = disp) + geom_point()}` then run `ggplot(mtcars) |> myFun()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is use a `list` of the elements to make a template, and then apply the template to different data frames:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) 

plot_template <- list(
  geom_boxplot(),
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", size = 14, vjust = 1),
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-2, 2.5, 0.5)),
  theme(text = element_text(size = 48))
)

# test
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg)) + plot_template

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) + plot_template
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This works beautifully, and is flexible with me changing other arguments before or after calling the list. I can even wrap more arguments in the "typical method" (i.e. `gg_custom <- ggplot(data) + scale_y_continuous(-2,2)`) and then do `gg_custom + plot_template + [more individual arguments]`. Game changer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the (underused/underappreciated) `%+%` operator, which substitutes a new `data` object and rebuilds the object.

Building on @TarJae's example,

```r
gg0 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) + plot_template
gg0 %+% mtcars +  aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg)
```

(if you were doing this with a bunch of data sets that all had the same variables you wouldn't need to add the `aes(...)` to override the previous mappings ...)